# Is there a standard name for a category all of whose contravariant hom functors are sheaves?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory

What prompted this question is the definition of a 
pseudogroup in [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/manifold):

Given a X a topological space. Then a pseudogroup is a subgroupoid of the groupoid of transitions between open sets in X, contains the groupoid of identity transitions, and satisfies a sheaf condition.

(Pseudogroups of continuous/smooth transitions are used to define the atlases for manifolds of the respective kind).

It seems to me a pseudogroup is morally a groupoid G that satisfies the sheaf condition for each presheaf G[-,V] for V an object of G.

Comment: You need more data than just a category to define what a sheaf is. See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/site .

Comment: What do you mean by a sheaf on arbitrary category? (One needs a Grothendieck topology on category to speak about sheaves. Well, any category has a Grothendieck topology in which all representable functors are sheaves.)

Comment: So a generalisation of a pseudogroup would be, G a groupoid; I turn G into a site by equipping it with a coverage J (that generates a grothendieck topology), then require J to be subcanonical so that every representable hom functor G[-,V] is a sheaf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The largest (weakest) Grothendieck topology where all contravariant hom functors are sheaves corresponds to the canonical topology. See:
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+topology